# Why won't iron golems spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My survival iron golem farm /

[image]

I set everything up (4 vertical blocks, 21x21 spawning platform, 4 villager cages, 16 villagers, and the killing platform down below, cleared out any doors/golems nearby), but no golems are spawning. Can someone tell me what I did wrong with my build?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your doors are not considered as houses for some reasons. Have a look at [Tutorials/Village mechanics](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Village_mechanics) for what you can change.

Answer (score 0):

That arrangement of blocks is correct. and assuming you have 10+ villagers near the farm. the only thing is you should have built this in spawn chunks.

How to locate spawn chunks:

to locate spawn chunks start by dropping dirt,nether-rack or any other useless item near to point where you had spawned at start of the game and go to nether and wait 5 mins. comeback to over-world once you have waited for 5 mins. If those items have been despawned then you have found the spawn chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Sunlight must be shining on the doors in order for it to be classified as a villager. Replace the blocks on top of the doors with glass or another transparent block.

Comment: that wouldnt make any sense, because a house is considered a door with anything NON opaque / transparent ontop of it. Meaning you have to provide a solid non transparent block in order for the doors to count.

Answer (score -2):

You can make a golem, with one iron block on the ground, then three on the top like you'd make a wither. Then, in the middle, place a pumpkin. I hope you understood that,

Comment: Although you can make golems this way this is not what the OP wants. The question is about a golem farm to kill them for loot.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm trying 

Answer (score -3):

Iron Golems can't be spawned artificially  despite having the correct amount of villagers. They only spawn at villages if a village naturally has at least 16 villagers.

Comment: I had a villager breeder down maybe 100 blocks away, and it was able to spawn iron golems just fine. The village where they came from was maybe 2000 blocks away (Nether transportation)

Comment: @MikeJ Yes but it isn't enough to just have 'villagers': Your golem farm must be **in** a 'village'. from the Wiki: *"Golems will spawn in a 16×16×6 area, centered between the 21 or more valid doors in a village if it has at least 10 villagers"*. Your farm is probably not considered a valid village.

Comment: @Robotnik agreed

Comment: *if a village naturally has at least 16 villagers*. thats wrong